# Really dumb clarification on logarithm domain.

Tags: calculus, analysis, logarithms

I have the inequality

$$\log(1+3x) \geq \log(4x-10)$$

Where $\log$ is meant in base $10$.\
Now, checking the respective domains, I found the whole domain is $$\Omega: x > \frac{5}{2}$$

So I can exponentiate, comparing the two arguments.

Yet I was wondering: if I apply log property, moving to the left all the terms, then I have

$$\log\left(\dfrac{1+3x}{4x-10}\right) \geq 0$$

But now the domain changes, reading

$$\Omega: x\in (-\infty, -1/3) \cup (5/2, +\infty)$$

Which one is correct? I am confused on this thing.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant logarithmic identity can be stated as follows.

> (Correct) For all *positive numbers* $x$ and $y$,
> $$ \log x - \log y = \log(x/y). $$

In this statement, all three logarithms in the equality are well-defined, because $x$ and $y$ are restricted to be positive numbers.  In particular, it does not say anything about the case $x \le 0$ or $y \le 0$.  You can only apply this statement when you know *a priori* that $x > 0$ and $y > 0$.

Compare the statement above to the following incorrect statement that you are suggesting:

> (Incorrect) For all *real numbers* $x$ and $y$,
> either
> $$ \log x - \log y = \log(x/y) $$
> is a well-defined and true equality,
> or $\log x - \log y$ and $\log(x/y)$ are both undefined.